# How can I connect to services in GCP from Google Cloud ML?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

I want to store information about a Cloud ML job to a Mongo DB server. The server is running on port `27017` a dedicated instance in my GCP project called `mongo`. I *can* access this server from other GCP instances (either on `<internal-ip>:27017` or simply the hostname `mongo:27017`) in the same project. But I cant connect to it from my Cloud ML jobs, nor can I find any access control settings for such scenarios.

**Is there a way to connect to tcp services running on GCP from Cloud ML?**

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your training jobs should have access to the public internet, so if you setup your DB on a public IP address, you will have access. However, at this time, you will be unable to access VMs on your internal network.

Comment: Thanks! Are there any public plans on when features such as networking control will be made available?